# Pandas groupwise row value adjustments

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by

I wrote a lambda function to adjust a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'types':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],'disruptions':['N','N','Y','N','N','N','N','N','N','N'],'actions':[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],'status':[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1],'status_2':[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1]})
```

My goal is to convert the 'status' column into 'status_2'. The logic is: within the same 'types' group, if 'action' is labeled as 1 & 'disruptions' is 'Y', then the next row of 'status_2' will be 0. Otherwise equal to 'status'.

Here is what I have:

```
df['status_2'] = df.groupby('types').apply(lambda x: 0 if x['disruptions'].shift(1) == 'Y' & x['actions'].shift(1) == 1 else x['status'])
```

The error is: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped[float64] array with a scalar of type[bool].

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create mask by `groupby`, convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and then use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), which for `True` values get `0`, another values are untouched:

```
f = lambda x: (x['disruptions'].shift(1) == 'Y') & (x['actions'].shift(1) == 1)
m = df.groupby('types').apply(f).values
print (m)
[False False False  True False False False False False False]

#changed column name for compare
df['status_2_new'] = df['status'].mask(m, 0)
print (df)
   actions disruptions  status  status_2 types  status_2_new
0        0           N       0         0     A             0
1        0           N       0         0     A             0
2        1           Y       0         0     A             0
3        0           N       1         0     A             0
4        0           N       1         1     A             1
5        0           N       0         0     B             0
6        0           N       0         0     B             0
7        1           N       0         0     B             0
8        0           N       1         1     B             1
9        0           N       1         1     B             1
```

Comment: error is in `groupby` ? with sample data or real data?

Comment: hi, I see a bug while implementing the code in production. 
my production data doesn't have types arranged in AABB order, it's in fact ABAB. so m is in AABB order, and the 
df[ 'status_2_new' ] = df[ 'status' ].mask(m, 0) code is an AABB assignment. This caused the production's ABAB data to have a misfit

Comment: I think you can use `df.groupby('types', sort=False)` for no sorting in groupby.

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work, could you point out what I should do if 'types' are in the ABABAB order?

Comment: Hmmm, is possible as first step sorting by `types` all data in df by `df = df.sort_values('types')` ? Because if not do you need process data by groups `aaa` `bbb` , then `aa` and `bbbb`(4 separately groups) if order `aaabbbaabbbb`?